# Writing First Web Services with Spring

Tags: web-services, spring, jboss

I am looking into writing my first web service with Spring. Can someone tell me of a good example on the internet.. I will be running this service in Jboss AS

Comment: You can check [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33094/Create-a-Simple-Web-Service-Using-JBossWS)

Answer (score 2):

I guess Spring's tutorial should be your first start point:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/tutorial.html